# On demand assets loading for WebView rendering

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

I have a scenario that, when a user connects to the server from the mobile app the scripts used for the Web View needs to be downloaded from the server. Then store it locally and uses this scripts for further Web View rendering.

Only when we upgrade the server the client should update the scripts from the server.

Is this possible to achieve this in Xamarin.Forms? If yes, can you share me your ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you could achieve this. One possible way is this:

1. Create an endpoint on your server that can respond to requests for the latest version number of your scripts.
2. [Query this endpoint from the app using httpclient](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/).
3. If the version number on the server is greater than the version number on the app, then query the server again to retrieve the scripts required, and [store them on the device](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files).

Comment: Is that stored script files can be accessed for web view?

Comment: @Karthik Yes. You can find more information on working with local files in the webview here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/#Content

Comment: Do i need any specific permission to download and store the data in local for iOS and Android app?